# MPAndroidChart Scatterchart in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, mpandroidchart

I am using the [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

I have multiple scattercharts in a ListView.
Every chart contains 365 xvalues (every day of the year).
The yvalues vary from 1 to 5.
The height of the charts is 150dp.
I would like to be able to zoom in, so I can see every single day.
But when I zoom in, the yvalues get out of range of the chart.
Is there a way to keep the yvalues within range of the chart?
I tried it with the next settings:

```
 holder.chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    holder.chart.setDragEnabled(true);
    holder.chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    holder.chart.setScaleMinima(3f, 0f);
    holder.chart.centerViewPort(xIndex, 3);
```

But when I drag from left to right or right to left, values just disappear from the chart, even when in range.

Has anyone any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This is your issue:

`holder.chart.setScaleMinima(3f, 0f);`

You are setting the scale value of the y-axis to zero. By doing that, you practically zoom out the chart into **infinity**. If you do not want to manipulate the zoom/scale of the y-axis, set the y-scale to 1f. Like this:

`holder.chart.setScaleMinima(3f, 1f);`

Comment: That part works, thanks. Still, when zooming all the values dissappear as soon as 1 of the same value reaches the side edges of the chart.

Comment: Hmmm, now I am testing, the y-axis still scales with y-scale set to 1f.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate the chart after centerViewPort, worked for me.

holder.chart.invalidate();