# How to set max zoom level for barchart in mpandroidchart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How to set max **zoom in** level for barchart in **mpandroidchart**?

Answer (score 0):

The [author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1590502/philipp-jahoda) answer that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955668/mpandroidchart-scatterchart-in-listview).

To set zoom limites use:

```
setScaleMinima(2f, 1f)
```